# Unable to convert argument for string insert function

Tags: c++

I need help with my homework. I have to write a program which multiplies random vowels in random numbers. Here's my code. I have included libraries: `iostream`, `string`, `cstdlib` and `ctime`.
When I compile, i get the following error:

> ```
> „std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>> std::basic_string<_Elem,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::insert(const std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>,const unsigned int,const _Elem)”: nie można dokonać konwersji argumentu 1 z „int” do „const std::_String_const_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<_Elem>>>”
> ```

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
  srand(time(0));
  string x;
  getline(cin, x);

  for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
    if (x[i] == 'a' || x[i] == 'e' || x[i] == 'i' || x[i] == 'o' ||
        x[i] == 'u' || x[i] == 'y' || x[i] == 'A' || x[i] == 'E' ||
        x[i] == 'I' || x[i] == 'O' || x[i] == 'U' || x[i] == 'Y') {
      int d = rand() % 5 + 1;
      for (int j = 0; j < d; j++) {
        x.insert(i, x[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  cout << x;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that you are calling the `std::string::insert` overload that accepts a `char`, but both of those overloads require you to give an `iterator` for the position as opposed to an index. See here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert  If you changed to call the overload that adds a count (which is what you are accomplishing with your loop), you could call `x.insert(i, d, x[i])`

Comment: Just a note - as @JimRhodes pointed out, if a string contains a vowel, you are going to end up never exiting your for loop, so you need to think about how you are approaching the problem and make some other adjustments to your code.

Comment: You should convert your letter to upper case or lower case before comparison.  Research `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a version of insert that takes a position, count and char. You will want to use that instead of for loop.

```
int d = rand() % 5 + 1;
x.insert(i, d, x[i]);
```

But I don't think your main loop will ever end because it will always match an inserted vowel.

Answer (score 1):

You can find `std::string::insert` overloads in [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) reference. None of the overloads are viable given the parameters you pass (`int` and `char`). Hence the error.

Comment: There is a viable one, this one `basic_string& insert( size_type index, size_type count, CharT ch );` and it is actually the one that would do exactly what is intended. With that overload you could remove the for loop for insertion.

Comment: @pstrjds How is that one viable? OP passes 2 parameters, not 3. OP could have called some other function and passed some other parameters, but the question is about this particular error.

Comment: Removed my downvote after the edit. My objection was with both the "no viable" statement along with saying that OP probably meant to pass an iterator when there is no iterator in the code. The combination led me to the conclusion that this answer was unhelpful. Obviously others disagree.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that while [there are many overloads to insert,](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)
 none of them are what you are using.

Here are is what you should try instead:

```
x.insert(i, 1, x[i]);
```